# Connecting to Amazon SES Java Spring Framework Mail

Tags: spring, email, jhipster, amazon-ses

I have been trying to get my application (Jhipster) to connect to Amazon SES, here are the config properties:

```
spring:
...
    mail:
        host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
        port: 587
        username: ...
        password: ...
        protocol: smtp
        tls: true
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
```

I have tried on other ports, and following the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html) from Amazon, however, using port 25, I get "SSL Plaintext Exception"

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Error in
>   getting welcome msg. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   Error in getting welcome msg  at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:432)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)

The SES Account is verified and has worked before, using **protocol: smtps, port: 465**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct configuration is:

```
mail:
    host: email-smtp.[region].amazonaws.com
    port: 465
    username: ...
    password: ...
    protocol: smtps
    debug: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
        starttls.enable: true
        starttls.required: true
        ssl.enable: true
    properties.mail.smtps:
        auth: true
```